# Abrindo camera do celular através do site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa noite,tenho um projeto em html, já está na forma responsiva, então lá no projecto existe uma necessidade de abrir a camera do móvel, gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso.

Comment: Navegadores não podem ter acesso a nada do sistema operacional por segurança. Você precisaria programar algum aplicativo (Android Studio, React Native, Ionic ...) que obtém a permissão de acessar o dispositivo

Comment: @Sveen Você não está 100% correto, ele pode usar um input file
`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`

Comment: Obrigado Leandro. Já queria admirar,  as veses quando as pessoas não sabem inventam qualquer coisa